# A context dependent Fortran scanner

Tags: flex-lexer

I am trying to generate a fortran lexer and parser automatically with flex & bison, however, I came across an error when scanning the following fortran language:
    *"if(i.le.20.and.j.le.10)"*
The reason I've found is,  *".and."* is a logical operator in fortran grammar, while a float-point number can be written as *"20."*. So my lexer would recognize *"20."* as a float-point number, basing on the rule *"matching the longest possible string"*, while the left string *"and.j.le.10"* has no rules to match.
  So how can I figure out this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve that problem with lex and yacc.  While there have been occasional backtracking yacc implementations, the problem here is at the level of lex.  The lexer would have to test successively longer strings until it is as long as possible before ***succeeding*** tokens would fail the rule.  lex doesn't do that: it advances through the input stream, backing up only to address ambiguities in the ***current*** token.  Whether lex or flex, the same answer.

Others solve the problem with a specially written lexical analyzer.  For instance, you could read a whole line and recursively split it into tokens.  After each proposed token, the lexer would recur from that point, looking for the next token.  If none is suitable (such as **`and.`**), the lexer would return an error.  The recursion would only complete if it reached the end of the line.

This is fairly straightforward with [Fortran 90's free form](http://ergodic.ugr.es/cphys/LECCIONES/FORTRAN/f77to90/a3.html#section1).  With the earlier versions, whitespace was largely irrelevant (except in an I/O format).

Further reading:

- [Parser generators with backtrack or extended lookahead capability](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/research/languages/csle/lookahead_backtrack.html)
- [Need FORTRAN grammar for lex & yacc](https://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/94-10-105) (1994 usenet posting)
- [bfor](https://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#bfor) (description of a Fortran preprocessor)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to preprocess the file to modify such lines to

```
if((i.le.20) .and. (j .le. 10)) then
```